# How to create javascript as pluggable into any website?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an HTML5 audio player but basically I want it to be pluggable into any website. So, in essense I want to allow the users of my website to copy the code and paste it into any other website and then my player should show upon on that particular site along with the images etc. How can I achieve such a functionality?

I want something like youtube where they give code and pasting it shows their video player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option would be with an iframe. Then you can be pretty sure that their and your javascript won't interfere. Also, you'd be able to change and update your HTML at any later time, to support new features.

This is the method most video-sharing sites (YouTube, Vimeo, and I think DailyMotion) use for embedding HTML5 video.